# Pivot Navigation

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have Pivot in my app:

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="menuPivot" SelectionChanged="PivotSelectionChanged">
            <phone:PivotItem Header="Search" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <local:SearchControl x:Name="search"/>
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="Favorites">
                <local:FavoritesControl x:Name="favorites" />
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="History">
                <local:HistoryControl x:Name="history" />
            </phone:PivotItem>

            <phone:PivotItem Header="NowPlaying">
                <local:NowPlayingPageControl x:Name="nowPlaying" />
            </phone:PivotItem>

        </phone:Pivot>
```

And i want to know how i can set the Pivot index inside the controls.Something like if a user press a button inside SearchControl so the pivot will navigate to now playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
menuPivot.SelectedItem = nowPlaying;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.pivot.selecteditem

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @NikolaiDante: The first line in the answer answers the question. The second line is the link. I was a little more terse than usual, but I show him/her how to fix the issue in the answer.